# How can I use floor function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can’t use floor function in my project.

What is problem?

```
int numAllSms = Math.Floor( (msg4SmsPart1.Count()) / 69) + Math.Floor((msg4SmsPart2.Count()) / 69) ;
```

My string is :

```
 String msg4SmsPart1 = "", msg4SmsPart2 = "" ;
```

It's my error: "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Floor(decimal)' and 'System.Math.Floor(double)'"

Comment: What error do you got?

Comment: What error message are you getting? You haven't said what is wrong.

Comment: Math.Floor returns either a decimal or a double so you probably have to cast the result before assigning it to an int variable.

Comment: Integer division?  Try converting msg4SmsPart1.Count() to double and divide it by 69.0

Comment: It's my error: "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Floor(decimal)' and 'System.Math.Floor(double)'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two problems:

- [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return a `double` or `decimal`; you're trying to assign it to an `int` variable
- Your divisions are being performed in integer arithmetic, which is presumably not what you were intending given that you're using `Math.Floor`.

I suspect you want:

```
int numAllSms = (int) (Math.Floor(msg4SmsPart1.Count() / 69.0) +
                       Math.Floor((msg4SmsPart2.Count() / 69.0));
```

Note the use of `69.0` instead of `69` so that it's a `double` literal, leading to floating point division.

It's not clear whether you actually want `Floor` or `Ceiling` though - I would have expected `Ceiling` to be more appropriate in this case. As noted in p.s.w.g's answer, you can just use integer arithmetic for all of this - if you want the `Ceiling` equivalent, you can use:

```
 int numAllSms = (msg4SmsPart1.Count() + 68) / 69
               + (msg4SmsPart1.Count() + 68) / 69;
```

Adding 68 before the division makes it effectively round any non-integer result up.

Answer (score 3):

[`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts and returns either a `double` or a `decimal`, so you'd have to cast the result to an `int` in order to asign the result to an `int` variable. You probably also intend to perform double or decimal devision here. The easiest way to do that is to write `69` as `69.0` (double) or `69m` (decimal):

```
int numAllSms = (int)(Math.Floor( (msg4SmsPart1.Count()) / 69m) + Math.Floor((msg4SmsPart2.Count()) / 69m));
```

However, because you're dealing with integers already, you can just skip calling `Math.Floor` and take advantage of integer arithmetic:

```
int numAllSms = (msg4SmsPart1.Count() / 69) + (msg4SmsPart2.Count() / 69);
```

See [/ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx):

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2.

Also, since it appears `msg4SmsPart1` and `msg4SmsPart2` are strings, this can be simplified to:

```
int numAllSms = (msg4SmsPart1.Length / 69) + (msg4SmsPart2.Length / 69);
```

Or just

```
int numAllSms = msg4SmsPart1.Length / 69 + msg4SmsPart2.Length / 69;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you can use it, but the result is always 0? Integer division will not return the precision you're looking for. You also need to cast the return value to an int to match the variable you're trying to assign to. Try casting the operand on either side of your division operators to a double:

```
int numAllSms = (int)Math.Floor((double)(msg4SmsPart1.Count()) / 69) + (int)Math.Floor((double)(msg4SmsPart2.Count()) / 69) ;
```